# See line breaks and carriage returns in editor

Tags: vim, newline, text-editor, line-breaks, carriage-return

Is there a text editor on Linux that allows me to see line breaks and carriage returns? Does Vim support this feature?

Comment: NOTE: sometimes newline ($) and carriage return (^M) are hidden in MANY color schemes, and also while using putty to ssh.

Comment: OP I think you should reconsider the selected answer. as the selected answer doesn't work. but CaptSaltyJack answer works well.

Comment: OP What will show BOTH is @arno 's solution.

I needed to see BOTH, because I have a file randomly using all 3 fileformats...

And arno 's solution works

Comment: You can also display the `fileformat` in the status bar. I have `[dos]` or `[unix]` display in my status bar.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

*Assuming your vim settings for `:set listchars=...` is set to visualize the characters you are attempting to *see*, in this case the carriage return characters (typed with CTL + V, CTRM + M) —— otherwise, as reported in many of the comments on this answer, the ^M character will not show on `:set list`*

`:set list` in Vim will show whitespace. End of lines show as '`$`'.

Comment: Same question here: http://superuser.com/questions/97692/vim-show-line-feeds-carriage-return

Comment: Incorrect, `:set list` will NOT show `^M` characters (CRs). Supplying the `-b` option to vi/vim will work. Or, once vim is loaded, type: `:e ++ff=unix`

Comment: FYI, to turn off the "set list" mode, use `:set nolist`

Comment: @Tomofumi an edit with your perposition will be welcome!

Comment: WRONG answer.   :set list will NOT show ^M characters (CRs). Use -b option to vi/vim will work.

Comment: As I understand it, Vim will show the ^M characters only if it thinks the `fileformat` of the file is `unix`. This usually happens when one or more lines ends with the `\n` unix-style line break character, but the others end with `\r\n` CRLF combination that Windows uses. Then the lines with the CRLF line ending will show the ^M character.

Comment: While what @Tomofumi says is perfectly correct, I prefer to do `:set list!` to switch between modes. Just faster to type, plus you can use vim's history to find the command faster, and just add (or remove) the '!' from the end of the command

Comment: Updated answer to clarify why `:set list` would not work as expected for many of you. It has to do with the configuration of `:set listchars=...`

Answer (score 343):

To disagree with the official answer: `:set list` alone will *not* show ^M characters (CRs).

Solutions that do work:

- `vim -b`  (add the `-b` option when starting vim)
  -or-
- `:e ++ff=unix` (while vim is running)

Comment: It's the Syntax.  `:help edit` shows `e[dit]! [++opt] [+cmd]`.   And `:help ++e` says _The [++opt] argument can be used to force the value of 'fileformat' [..]_.

Comment: just to clarify, `:set list` shows newline (`$`), `:e ++ff=unix` shows CR (`^M`); if you want to see both, `:set list` then `:e ++ff=unix`

Comment: To expand on @dennis's comment, `:set ff=unix` tells Vim to *change* the line endings to unix style (as part of setting the fileformat), so the ^M characters are no longer there (and so are not displayed). `:e ++ff=unix` tells it to force-set the fileformat as `unix` without actually changing the contents. So vim reads it like a Unix file, sees the CR characters as extra and displays them as ^M.

Comment: Does this command change under Mac? I'm still not able to see CRs

Comment: Neither still doesn't work for me in `vim` for some reason... I mean neither `-b` option, nor `:e ++ff=unix` when inside :(

Comment: all right, :e ++ff=unix worked. Now how do I turn it off?

Comment: Can be turned off (or back) to either Windows with `:e ++ff=dos` or Mac `:e ++ff=mac`

Comment: `:e ++ff=unix` or `-b` shows nothing special in my source `.cpp` files. What's wrong?

Comment: Not sure why these methods do not work for me. I have just found a convenient way to indicate the `\n` or `\r` or `\r\n`. Just search them and they will be highlighted. Type `/\n` or `/\r` or `/\r\n`.

Comment: how do I put this into my .vimrc file

Answer (score 81):

*vi* shows newlines (LF character, code `x0A`) by showing the subsequent text on the next line.

Use the `-b` switch for binary mode. For example , `vi -b filename` or `vim -b filename --`.

It will then show CR characters (`x0D`), which are not normally used in Unix style files, as the characters `^M`.

Comment: I typically dont need to see the line ending, because I mostly work in `Unix` environment. But I would like to be warned about Windows type line endings if there is any in the file. Will `vi -b filename` or `:set binary` just show `^M` if it is a windows type file and no other line endings otherwise?

Answer (score 43):

Just to clarify why `:set list` won't show CR's as `^M` without `e ++ff=unix` and why `:set list` has nothing to do with `^M`'s.

Internally when Vim **reads** a file into its buffer, it replaces all line-ending characters with its own representation (let's call it `$`'s). To determine what characters should be removed, it firstly detects in what format line endings are stored in a file. If there are only CRLF `'\r\n'` or only CR `'\r'` or only LF `'\n'` line-ending characters, then the `'fileformat'` is set to `dos`, `mac` and `unix` respectively.

When `list` option is set, Vim displays `$` character when the line break occurred no matter what `fileformat` option has been detected. It uses its own internal representation of line-breaks and that's what it displays.

Now when you **write** buffer to the disc, Vim inserts line-ending characters according to what `fileformat` options has been detected, essentially converting all those internal `$`'s with appropriate characters. If the `fileformat` happened to be `unix` then it will simply write `\n` in place of its internal line-break.

The trick is to force Vim to read a `dos` encoded file as `unix` one. The net effect is that it will remove all `\n`'s leaving `\r`'s untouched and display them as `^M`'s in your buffer. Setting `:set list` will additionally show internal line-endings as `$`. After all, you see `^M$` in place of `dos` encoded line-breaks.

Also notice that `:set list` has nothing to do with showing `^M`'s. You can check it by yourself (make sure you have disabled `list` option first) by inserting single CR using `CTRL-V` followed by `Enter` in insert mode. After writing buffer to disc and opening it again you will see `^M` despite `list` option being set to 0.

You can find more about file formats on http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_format or by typing`:help 'fileformat'` in Vim.

Answer (score 12):

Try the following command.

```
:set binary
```

In Vim, this should do the same thing as using the "-b" command line option. If you put this in your startup (i.e., *.vimrc*) file, it will always be in place for you.

On many *nix systems, there is a "dos2unix" or "unix2dos" command that can process the file and correct any suspected line ending issues. If there aren't any problems with the line endings, the files will not be changed.

Comment: Unfortunately in my system (Ubuntu 16.04) `set binary` is not the same as `vim -b filename.py`. Any idea why? I did check the `help` and it does seem that what you say is generally correct. How do I figure out why this is so?

Comment: `:e ++ff=unix` does show the `^M` correctly and doesn't show it when I use `unix` type files.. So I guess the problem is solved for now...

Answer (score 8):

By using [cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)) and [`-A`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cat) you can see new lines as `$` and tabs as `^I`:

```
cat -A myfile
```

Comment: 'cat -A' is not as portable as 'cat -e'.  -A is supported by GNU coreutils version of cat(1), but not other implementations (e.g., bsd, macos, etc.).

Comment: And `:%!cat -A` to use in vim (although that changes the contents of the buffer of course)

Comment: [See answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389616/216300) for more details: When you do `cat -A myfile`, then `hello^M$` means crlf endings, `hello$` for lf endings.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you to edit your *.vimrc* file, for running a list of commands.

Edit your *.vimrc* file, like this:

```
cat >> ~/.vimrc <<EOF
set ffs=unix
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencoding=utf-8
set listchars=eol:¶
set list
EOF
```

When you're executing Vim, the commands in file *.vimrc* are executed, and you can see this example:

```
My line with CRLF eol here ^M¶
```

Answer (score 0):

You can view break lines using the [gedit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gedit) editor.

First, if you don't have it installed, for Debian/Ubuntu/Mint based distros:

```
sudo apt-get install gedit
```

For Fedora/CentOS/RedHat based distros:

```
sudo dnf install gedit
```

or

```
sudo yum install gedit
```

Now, install **gedit plugins**:

```
sudo apt-get install gedit-plugins
```

or

Under **Gnome2**, user plugins were put into `~/.gnome2/gedit/plugins/`
For **Gnome3**: `~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/`

Download the plugins from:  https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-plugin-guide.html.en#gedit-additional-plugins

and select **Draw Spaces** plugin, enter on Preferences, and chose **Draw new lines**:

[image]

[image]

Using [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code), you can install the **Line endings** extension.

[Sublime Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) 3 has a plugin called **RawLineEdit** that will display line endings and allow the insertion of arbitrary line-ending type

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and start type the name of the plugin, and toggle to show line endings.

Comment: `apt-get` will not work on all Linux systems (this question's scope). Perhaps state the assumptions? [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29)? [Linux Mint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint)? [Ubuntu MATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE)? [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, I added steps for CentOS,RedHad,Fedora (for Gnome desktop environments)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following alias to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases`:

```
alias vidos='vi  -c ":e ++ff=unix" -c "set list"'
```

Then you can use `vidos` to edit the file and see newline as `$` and carriage return as `^M`.