# How to show linebreaks and carriage returns in vim, but ONLY inside paragraphs of text?

Tags: vim, whitespace

[Possibly related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860519/see-line-breaks-and-carriage-returns-in-editor)

I know that `set list` will show all linebreaks/carriage returns in vim.

But I would like them to show *only* when they are on a line that has text.

Is there a way to have `set list` work selectively?

The reason for this is simple:  when I paste a bunch of text, while not in paste mode, I often get a garbled paragraph full of whitespace.  I would like to be able to see that whitespace, but only if it is in a textual area.

Comment: can you switch on `list` and check the just pasted text with your eyes?  Or paste to a new buffer. The feature you are asking doesn't exist

Comment: You can highlight whitespace by searching for it. Do take a look at this http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_unwanted_spaces